# Calling a Javascript function on a button

Tags: javascript, function, cordova, storage

I'm trying to developed an android app with PhoneGap. I'm using the Storage Plugin and following the documentation provided by PhoneGap on that. I came across a function definition of a Select Query. I was thinking about making a button to fire that query but I just don't know how. I kind of newbie in JavaScript. 
Here it is the code of the function:

```
 function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
 }
```

I tried to make the button like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<button onclick="queryDB();">SELECT</button>
```

I believe it's missing something between the parentheses but I can't figure it out what is it.
Thanks, Eva.

Comment: where is `tx` coming from? if you have it initialized as a global variable AND you have querySuccess and errorDB functions defined, this could work... maybe posting few more lines of code would help?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parameter `tx`.

```
<button onclick="queryDB(tx);">SELECT</button>
```

But there should be a global variable `tx`.